# Difference between functions and non-functions?

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble understanding why I am getting two different outputs when I run these two different instances of code. As far as I can tell there is no difference. I'm currently learning about justifying text so I thought I'd write something to balance the text in the center. Since then I've learned about `str.center()`, but I'm still curious regarding the difference between these two cells below.

The input for each is `input(Juice)`.

```
def orangeJuice():
    x = input()
    n = len(x)
    x.rjust(2*n, '$').ljust(3*n, '$')

orangeJuice()
```

--> Juice

```
x = input()
n = len(x)
x.rjust(2*n, '$').ljust(3*n, '$')
```

--> $$$$$Juice$$$$$

[Screenshot of my Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q70Mq.png)

Also, I'm happy to accept tips for improving my questions, thank you.

Chris

Comment: The former is a function that does *not* return anything, nor does it print something. In the outer part, the there is no function, so the "interpreter" prints the result (if *not* `None`) to the console.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is how the line `x.rjust(2*n, '$').ljust(3*n, '$')` gets handled.

That line is an expression statement. That is, it has a return value, like any other expression. When you run an expression statement most of the time, the return value gets discarded. It might still be worth doing anyway, for its side effects, but you don't normally use an expression statement for its return value.

When running at the top level of an interactive interpreter session, an expression statement gets handled differently. Instead of the return value being ignored, it gets processed by the "P" part of the REPL (the Read-Eval-Print Loop). Such a loop is common to interactive interpreters of many languages (the specific name comes from LISP, as I understand it). In Python, the loop works by running each statement in turn. It checks the return value of any expression statements, and if it's not `None`, the `repr` of the result is printed out (other statement types never have return values, so they never print anything).

That's why the `x.rjust(2*n, '$').ljust(3*n, '$')` gives an output when you run it at the top level of your interactive session. If you ran it as part of a script, it would behave like the version that was in a function, and the value would be discarded silently.

A better way of handling this situation might be to explicitly `print` whatever output you want. This can work in any context, not only in an interactive session. If you do `print(x.rjust(2*n, '$').ljust(3*n, '$'))`, it will just work. Note that `print` calls `str` on its arguments, rather than `repr`, so the output won't be exactly the same (you won't get quotation marks or escape sequences in place of special characters in the output, for instance).

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that makes so much more sense.